# BeautifulSoup not working in google colab

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I have tried the below code in google colab but it gives an error which i have also shown below

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (4.6.3)

```
from beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
----> 1 from beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the "Open Examples" button below.

---

Than i also tried

```
!apt install BeautifulSoup4
```

> E: Unable to locate package BeautifulSoup4

```
!apt install BeautifulSoup
```

> E: Unable to locate package BeautifulSoup

I have also tried the above commands without exclamation mark (!). other packages were installed but beautifulsoup4 is not installing neither it is allowing to import.

I appreciate if someone can guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for importing BeautifulSoup use that one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

there's usual case a different package naming while installing and the step of importing/using

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
from beautifulsoup4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Try out

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
! pip install bs4
```

It worked very well in Google colaboratory.